# Y axes label for a d3.js bar chart appears inverted

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I have a d3.js bar chart that is okay for the most part. I want my Y axes label to become horizontal as the text is pretty big, so I am trying to rotate it by 180 degree which makes the text inverted.

```
      svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", "-.55em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");     //works fine


svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-180)")    //rotated by 180 and text gets inverted
  .attr("y", 5)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("avg_facebook_usage_rank");
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishy1988/jpbnmjro/6/)

Comment: I believe you mean **vertical** and **90 degrees**: https://jsfiddle.net/fybtrrLj/

Comment: Ohh. that works too. When I tried with -90, it was inside the graph and looking weird. now I see it is outside.